# How can one get a read/write speed for a given disk?

Tags: python, windows

I have multiple disks mounted on my Windows 10 PC and a program that regularly makes i/o operations on these disks. I am trying to log the data on memory usage, cpu time and disk i/o speed at the moment of calling the function via a python script - somewhat similar to what Task Manager Performance window does. While I got cpu and memory covered by *psutil* module, I can't figure the simple way to retrieve the disk i/o speeds.

How would you advice to implement it?

Comment: Maybe this module can help https://pypi.org/project/disk-bench/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Ensure to put in an empty directory, as it will get full of written, read files for testing.

**rwrite.py**

```
import sys
import ctypes

def run_as_admin(argv=None, debug=False):
    shell32 = ctypes.windll.shell32
    if argv is None and shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        return True
        
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        # Support pyinstaller wrapped program.
        arguments = map(unicode, argv[1:])
    else:
        arguments = map(unicode, argv)
    argument_line = u' '.join(arguments)
    executable = unicode(sys.executable)
    if debug:
        print 'Command line: ', executable, argument_line
    ret = shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u"runas", executable, argument_line, None, 1)
    if int(ret) <= 32:
        return False
    return None
    
from __future__ import division, print_function  # for compatability with py2

import os, sys
from random import shuffle
import argparse
import json

try:  # if Python >= 3.3 use new high-res counter
    from time import perf_counter as time
except ImportError:  # else select highest available resolution counter
    if sys.platform[:3] == 'win':
        from time import clock as time
    else:
        from time import time


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Arguments', formatter_class = argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                        required=False,
                        action='store',
                        default=os.getcwd(),
                        help='The file to read/write to')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--size',
                        required=False,
                        action='store',
                        type=int,
                        default=128,
                        help='Total MB to write')
    parser.add_argument('-w', '--write-block-size',
                        required=False,
                        action='store',
                        type=int,
                        default=1024,
                        help='The block size for writing in bytes')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--read-block-size',
                        required=False,
                        action='store',
                        type=int,
                        default=512,
                        help='The block size for reading in bytes')
    parser.add_argument('-j', '--json',
                        required=False,
                        action='store',
                        help='Output to json file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


class Benchmark:

    def __init__(self, file,write_mb, write_block_kb, read_block_b):
        self.file = file
        self.write_mb = write_mb
        self.write_block_kb = write_block_kb
        self.read_block_b = read_block_b
        wr_blocks = int(self.write_mb * 1024 / self.write_block_kb)
        rd_blocks = int(self.write_mb * 1024 * 1024 / self.read_block_b)
        self.write_results = self.write_test( 1024 * self.write_block_kb, wr_blocks)
        self.read_results = self.read_test(self.read_block_b, rd_blocks)

    def write_test(self, block_size, blocks_count, show_progress=True):
        '''
        Tests write speed by writing random blocks, at total quantity
        of blocks_count, each at size of block_size bytes to disk.
        Function returns a list of write times in sec of each block.
        '''
        f = os.open(self.file, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY, 0o777)  # low-level I/O

        took = []
        for i in range(blocks_count):
            if show_progress:
                # dirty trick to actually print progress on each iteration
                sys.stdout.write('\rWriting: {:.2f} %'.format(
                    (i + 1) * 100 / blocks_count))
                sys.stdout.flush()
            buff = os.urandom(block_size)
            start = time()
            os.write(f, buff)
            os.fsync(f)  # force write to disk
            t = time() - start
            took.append(t)

        os.close(f)
        return took

    def read_test(self, block_size, blocks_count, show_progress=True):
        '''
        Performs read speed test by reading random offset blocks from
        file, at maximum of blocks_count, each at size of block_size
        bytes until the End Of File reached.
        Returns a list of read times in sec of each block.
        '''
        f = os.open(self.file, os.O_RDONLY, 0o777)  # low-level I/O
        # generate random read positions
        offsets = list(range(0, blocks_count * block_size, block_size))
        shuffle(offsets)

        took = []
        for i, offset in enumerate(offsets, 1):
            if show_progress and i % int(self.write_block_kb * 1024 / self.read_block_b) == 0:
                # read is faster than write, so try to equalize print period
                sys.stdout.write('\rReading: {:.2f} %'.format(
                    (i + 1) * 100 / blocks_count))
                sys.stdout.flush()
            start = time()
            os.lseek(f, offset, os.SEEK_SET)  # set position
            buff = os.read(f, block_size)  # read from position
            t = time() - start
            if not buff: break  # if EOF reached
            took.append(t)

        os.close(f)
        return took

    def print_result(self):
        result = ('\n\nWritten {} MB in {:.4f} s\nWrite speed is  {:.2f} MB/s'
                  '\n  max: {max:.2f}, min: {min:.2f}\n'.format(
            self.write_mb, sum(self.write_results), self.write_mb / sum(self.write_results),
            max=self.write_block_kb / (1024 * min(self.write_results)),
            min=self.write_block_kb / (1024 * max(self.write_results))))
        result += ('\nRead {} x {} B blocks in {:.4f} s\nRead speed is  {:.2f} MB/s'
                   '\n  max: {max:.2f}, min: {min:.2f}\n'.format(
            len(self.read_results), self.read_block_b,
            sum(self.read_results), self.write_mb / sum(self.read_results),
            max=self.read_block_b / (1024 * 1024 * min(self.read_results)),
            min=self.read_block_b / (1024 * 1024 * max(self.read_results))))
        print(result)
        print(ASCIIART)


    def get_json_result(self,output_file):
        results_json = {}
        results_json["Written MB"] = self.write_mb
        results_json["Write time (sec)"] = round(sum(self.write_results),2)
        results_json["Write speed in MB/s"] = round(self.write_mb / sum(self.write_results),2)
        results_json["Read blocks"] = len(self.read_results)
        results_json["Read time (sec)"] = round(sum(self.read_results),2)
        results_json["Read speed in MB/s"] = round(self.write_mb / sum(self.read_results),2)
        with open(output_file,'w') as f:
            json.dump(results_json,f)


def main():
    args = get_args()
    benchmark = Benchmark(args.file, args.size, args.write_block_size, args.read_block_size)
    if args.json is not None:
        benchmark.get_json_result(args.json)
    else:
        benchmark.print_result()
    os.remove(args.file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ret = run_as_admin()
    if ret is True:
        print 'I have admin privilege.'
        raw_input('Press ENTER to exit.')
    elif ret is None:
        print 'I am elevating to admin privilege.'
        raw_input('Press ENTER to exit.')
    else:
        print 'Error(ret=%d): cannot elevate privilege.' % (ret, )
    main()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't help. I don't want to create write load on the disk, I only need to monitor the existing i/o stats. While good for checking for max i/o speeds, it's not what I can use to look at the existing load.

Comment: @nogoodsz Oh, okay. I suppose you could use this : https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/02/how-fast-are-your-disks-find-out-the-open-source-way-with-fio/

Comment: once again, this is a benchmarking test that's trying to make an i/o operation of its own, instead of accessing what's already going on. I will not get an accurate reading from that.